# insert a value inside an array of vector

Tags: c++, vector

//im new to vectors and im really having a hard time of inserting values inside a vector. particularly the waiting vector. i was hoping i could get the waiting time by  =(burst[i] + waiting[i - 1]);

```
int value;
int size;
vector<int>process;
vector<int>burst;
vector<int>arrival;
vector<int>waiting;
vector<int>turnaround;
vector<int>completion;

void fcfs()
{
    cout << "Enter the no. of processes: "; cin >> size;
    cout << "Enter the Arrival Time of each Processes: "; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> value;
        arrival.push_back(value);
    }
    cout << "Enter the Burst Time of each Processes: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> value;
        burst.push_back(value);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        waiting.push_back(burst[i] + waiting[i - 1]);
    }
```

Comment: When i is 0, `waiting[i - 1]` would be an out of bounds access.

Comment: Also, determining waiting time will be more involved and will depend on the scheduling algorithm in use. It will also need to account for arrival time.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for all these variables to be global? They are probably better suited to be function-local variables.

Comment: i forgot to include that it is inside a class

Answer (score 0):

Change the last loop to:

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    waiting.push_back(burst[i] + waiting[i - 1]);
```

Now, it will not access the container out-of-bounds. Use the built-in member function `at()`. It throws an exception when out-of-bounds elements are accessed.